# Update a row with old value in some column using trigger Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, triggers, oracle12c

when I use a trigger (Oracle v11 and v12) on a table update, I want two columns of each row to contain the old value. The trigger used is below:

```
SET DEFINE OFF;
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER X_Exclusion_Sequence_Field3
AFTER UPDATE ON CATGPENREL
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    old_sequence NUMBER;
    old_field3 NUMBER(20,5);
BEGIN
    if (:OLD.SEQUENCE <> :NEW.SEQUENCE OR :OLD.FIELD3 <> :NEW.FIELD3) then
        -- backup
        select SEQUENCE, FIELD3 into old_sequence, old_field3 from CATGPENREL where CATGROUP_ID = 
        :NEW.CATGROUP_ID and CATALOG_ID = :NEW.CATALOG_ID and CATENTRY_ID = :NEW.CATENTRY_ID;
        
        update CATGPENREL 
        set SEQUENCE = old_sequence, FIELD3 = old_field3 
        where CATGROUP_ID = :NEW.CATGROUP_ID and CATALOG_ID = :NEW.CATALOG_ID and CATENTRY_ID = :NEW.CATENTRY_ID;
    end if;
END;
/
```

When I update I get the following error:

```
update CATGPENREL set sequence = 1, LASTUPDATE = sysdate where CATGROUP_ID = 3074457345616688681 and CATALOG_ID = 3074457345616684418 and CATENTRY_ID = 3074457345616734707
Report error -
ORA-04091: The ORAWCSI.CATGPENREL table is being edited, the trigger / function cannot read it
ORA-06512: a "ORAWCSI.X_EXCLUSION_SEQUENCE_FIELD3", line 7
ORA-04088: error while executing the trigger 'ORAWCSI.X_EXCLUSION_SEQUENCE_FIELD3'
```

Could you kindly help me?

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I have completely misunderstood, I think what you are trying to do is this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER X_Exclusion_Sequence_Field3
BEFORE UPDATE ON CATGPENREL
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   if (:OLD.SEQUENCE <> :NEW.SEQUENCE OR :OLD.FIELD3 <> :NEW.FIELD3) then
      :NEW.sequence := :OLD.sequence;
      :NEW.field3 = :OLD.field3;
   end if;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to change value at any cost irrespective of any condition, then below code Works.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER X_Exclusion_Sequence_Field3
BEFORE UPDATE ON CATGPENREL
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
      :NEW.sequence := :OLD.sequence;
      :NEW.field3 = :OLD.field3;
END;
```

If you need condition as well, then you need to handle null case as well, Assuming SEQUENCE and FIELD3 are number datatype

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER X_Exclusion_Sequence_Field3
BEFORE UPDATE ON CATGPENREL
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   if (NVL(:OLD.SEQUENCE,-999) <> NVL(:NEW.SEQUENCE,-999) OR NVL(:OLD.FIELD3,-999) <> NVL(:NEW.FIELD3,-999)) then
      :NEW.sequence := :OLD.sequence;
      :NEW.field3 = :OLD.field3;
   end if;
END;
```